# Android - Camera permissions denied without prompting

Tags: android, android-camera, android-external-storage

I was running into issues with the manual process behind requesting permissions (just kept falling into the 'denied' code), so I switched over to using Dexter to simplify.  I implemented the following code in onCreate(), and I did a fresh install of the app:

```
Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "GRANTED!");
                    initCamera();
                }
                @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DENIED!");
                }
                @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "PERMISSION RATIONAL SHOULD BE SHOWN!");

                }
            }).check();
```

It immediately falls into the "DENIED!" log, and it never even prompts me.  I tried this particular code to attempt multiple permissions (which is ultimately what I need to do):

```
Dexter.withActivity(activity)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Accepted: " + report.getGrantedPermissionResponses().size() + " | Denied: " + report.getDeniedPermissionResponses().get(0).getPermissionName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "continuing permissions request..");

                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            })
            .check();
```

It prompts for permissions to Record Audio, then it asks about Access to photos/media/files on the device (it never asks about Camera).  Then once that's done, it prints the log: "Accepted 3 | Denied: android.permission.CAMERA".  It denies it without even prompting me again.

My Manifest is set properly to have CAMERA in the proper place (outside of the 'application' tag).  See below for reference:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
etc..
```

Odd thing is that when I go into Settings > Applications > MyApp, the Camera option is not even displayed in there.

I don't think it's an issue with Dexter, since it's doing basically the same thing when I set it up manually (and I confirmed that it's definitely setup properly in that case after looking at a few top S.O. posts).

Any thoughts on what the issue could be here?  FYI - I'm using a Galaxy S6, OS 6.0.2.  The other users experiencing this seem to be other devices with 6.0+ OS.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Testing various devices, it works on some and does not work on some:

- Moto X (OS 5.0) - Broken
- Nexus 5 (OS 7.0) - Works
- Samsung S6 (OS 6.0.1) - Broken
- Broken Moto X (OS 6.0) - Works

Doesn't seem to be a solid pattern.. Definitely strange.  I also started a brand new project and ran the same code - worked fine and allowed access to my camera.  So it doesn't appear to be fully device-specific..

Comment: Have you uninstalled the app and tried after that?

Comment: Yep, I have tried uninstalling/re-installing the app, rebooting the device, etc.  The issue persists. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue with this turned out to be a third-party library, which had this line in their Manifest, overriding our own permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove" />
```

The solution was either to manually import their project as a module (rather than use gradle), and then comment out that line, OR more simple - you can add "tools:node="replace"" to the end of the main project's CAMERA permission line, and it works fine after that; no need to import the project with the latter approach.

Comment: By third party did you mean Dexter or some other library?

Comment: The library that was causing this issue is actually Kite.ly.  https://github.com/OceanLabs/Android-Print-SDK

Answer (score 1):

What you need is native runtime permissions not dexter, Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

> `// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
>   int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
>           Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION);`
>
> then what you need is to request a certain permission if that check is false,

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION},
            MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

Bare in ind that you need to as well declare them also in the manifest, based on what you have shown still that was already done. [For more information](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response, but yes I had that initially setup exactly as you specified, and the issue still persisted exactly how it's doing with Dexter.  Furthermore, I see that the Dexter library is frequently updated, and nowhere in their documentation do I see that it does not support 6.0+.  So I would be surprised if it doesn't support it.  The way I'm using it is not at app launch; I'm using it when the activity is launched, and it's treated just the same as doing it manually.

Also, please see details in my post - the Camera permission is not even an option in Settings.  Thoughts?

Comment: post your full error in your question so further analysis can be undertaken.\

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else can be posted?  There are no errors; it simply just returns a denied status for Camera and not the other permissions.  It does this for both Dexter and doing it manually.  Let me know if there is any other info I can post.  Other than what I've posted, I don't know of anything else to share.

Comment: You said you was using runtime permissions before, normally it gives a detail error message for any given error.

Comment: A key point you made was that this error was only persisting on devices with api level >=  6.0+, therefore it is run time permission i had the same problem. There is probably another bug somewhere.

Comment: We have only tested on 6.0+ devices, but it could be an issue on lower OS versions.  There is no error when I use runtime permissions manually.  It falls into the "onRequestPermissionsResult()" callback method, and "grantResults" contains a -1 where the CAMERA permissions is set.  Meaning it's denied (just as Dexter does it).  This activity simply runs this code in the onCreate().  I definitely believe there could be a bug somewhere else, but I don't see what could possibly be affecting this outside of this Activity and the Manifest?

Comment: what you could is perform  strip down removal process, where you incrementally take parts of your of or relating to the base issue, run it and reevaluate it again.. this way the error can be spotted...

Comment: The code provided is the most stripped-down code possible with both Dexter and the manual requesting of permissions.  It's not working period, and there's nothing to strip down, unfortunately.  What is provided is all that's there, nothing more (with regards to permissions).

Comment: So the third party library caused all the ruckus

Comment: Yep, it was painful to track down. :(  I appreciate your assistance regardless!

Comment: what exactly gave u the impression that was the problem for future references

Comment: In order to catch this, I actually had to step back through recent git commits (I knew it worked fine at one point).  So I went back to when it worked, then went forward each commit, one by one, until it broke.  It broke with the Kite.ly library implementation that we put in place alongside making the app Multidex.  I then tried both removing the lib and removing Multidex, and it turned out the lib.  Looked at their Manifest source code and bingo, spotted the permission (I confirmed this was the issue by manually importing the lib and commenting out that line).

Comment: Wow, sounds like a night mare, nice job though. !