# Dexter Permissions Automatically Declining?

Tags: java, android

I have code that asks for permission to read_external_storage, and then it will carry out a function. However, it is automatically declining without asking anything, and I can't run the functions. I have looked at this: [Android - Camera permissions denied without prompting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212814/android-camera-permissions-denied-without-prompting)

... but none of the answers solve my problem. Is there any other solutions?

Here is my function:

```
private void checkPermission() {
    Dexter.withContext(getContext())
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    displayAudios();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setTitle("Permission Required")
                            .setMessage("This app requires permission to read external storage to display audio files.")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> token.continuePermissionRequest())
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> token.cancelPermissionRequest())
                            .show();
                }
            })
            .check();
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.tts">
    <!-- Other permissions and features -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TTS"
        tools:targetApi="34">
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!-- Activities, services, etc. -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: What API level are you testing on?

Comment: The target sdk is 34, and the min sdk is 24, and I am testing on 33 @ianhanniballake

Comment: Why do you need "tools:node="replace"" in READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?